# Use SQL Server 2005 tools targeting a 2008 instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 2005 on my machine. I also have a copy of SS 2008 Express Management Studio (with SS 2008 Express loaded locally) on my machine.

Is there a way to copy the tools (Profiler, Tuning advisor,etc) from SSMS 2005 to SSMS 2008 Express?

I don't have permission to run those tools on the 2005 server, which is why I have a 2008 Express copy running locally.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have permission to run those tools on the 2005 server" - it's on your local PC right?

Comment: The 2005 server is compnay run and I only have read/update permissions. The 2008 express is local and I have admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

In general tools written for an earlier version of software will not work on the newer version as the tool was written when the newer version did not exist.

If you are thinking of developing on express version of 2008 and then deploying to your company's 2005 servers this is a particularly bad idea. Never develop in a newer version of software than production servers have as things you do will not work.

If you need those tools for your job for the 2005 database, then formally (in writing) explain why you need them and ask to be given the rights to run them. If they won't give you the rights, then ask who can do those tasks for you when they are needed to be done. And then give that person those tasks to do.

Comment: In addition to HLGEM's answer, you could also download and install SQL Server 2005 Express for (limited) testing: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=220549B5-0B07-4448-8848-DCC397514B41&displaylang=en